# How do I Lock icon positions in the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

How can I lock (i.e. making sure the icons order cannot move anymore) my icons on the Ubuntu dock? Is there any extension to do this?

[image]

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME 3.36.2.   

I am using the b00merang Theme,  MacOS - https://www.pling.com/p/1226871/

On my Windows 10 SDD, I have Nexus dock, which it has a feature to lock your icons in place and in order.

Comment: I would like to have the Ubuntu launcher to have same features as Nexus dock.

Comment: What I meant was you're using GNOME with Ubuntu Dock, *not* Unity and Unity Launcher.

Comment: Ubuntu dock also offers an option to pin an icon by adding it to favourites. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"? Making the icon permanently visible, on the dock, or making sure the order cannot anymore be changed?

Comment: I assume you want the whole size of dock icons to be fixed. If you are using Dash-to-dock, then you can change it in Dash-to-Dock-->Position and Size --> Enable Fixed icon size: scroll to reveal other icons

Comment: Yes,  making sure the icons order cannot move anymore.